# JPA query exception

Tags: java, mysql, orm, jpa, jpql

I have a query builded with `EntityManager`:

```
Query q = em
    .createQuery("SELECT * FROM :table WHERE username = :username AND password = MD5(:password)")
    .setParameter("table", User.class.getName())
    .setParameter("username", txtLogin.getText())
    .setParameter("password", passPassword.getPassword())
;

User user = (User) q.getSingleResult();
```

but I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An
>   exception occurred while creating a
>   query in EntityManager:
>   Exception
>   Description: Syntax error parsing the
>   query [SELECT * FROM :table WHERE
>   username = :username AND password =
>   MD5(:password)], line 1, column 7:
>   unexpected token [*].

How to fix it ?

Is it impossible to use `*` in queries ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPQL syntax is different from SQL, you do

```
Select T from Thingy T
```

instead of

```
Select * from Thingy
```

But that's only part of your problem. `SELECT t FROM :table t` won't work either, as parameters are not allowed in the `from` clause, but only in the `where` clause. So you must do it something like this:

```
Query q = em
    .createQuery("SELECT u FROM " + User.class.getName()
    + "u WHERE username = :username AND password = MD5(:password)")
    .setParameter("username", txtLogin.getText())
    .setParameter("password", passPassword.getPassword())
    ;
```

Also, there is no `MD5()` function in JPQL, so to use MD5 you either have to do that in java code or use a native SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot use `*` like that.

This is how to do it. Note even the SELECT is optional

```
 Query q = em
    .createQuery("FROM " + User.class.getName() + " WHERE username = :username AND password = MD5(:password)")
    .setParameter("username", txtLogin.getText())
    .setParameter("password", passPassword.getPassword())
    ;

User user = (User) q.getSingleResult();
```

With SELECT you can do like this:

```
Query q = em
    .createQuery("SELECT us FROM " + User.class.getName() + "us WHERE username = :username AND password = MD5(:password)")
    .setParameter("username", txtLogin.getText())
    .setParameter("password", passPassword.getPassword())
    ;
```

Comment: Which part of the JPA spec says that "SELECT" is optional ? In particular, in section 4.2.1 of the JPA2 spec we have "select_statement :: = select_clause from_clause [where_clause] [groupby_clause] [having_clause] [orderby_clause]" The "select_clause" is not optional at all

Comment: I don't know about the spec. However, if you want a `select * from` then you don't need to type SELECT. You can just write FROM. Perhaps it is hibernate that supports this, and not jpa specifically.